# How can I keep two characters after a comma?

Tags: r, regex

I have data on a metropolitan area and want to extract out the city info.

An example is

```
test <- c("Akron, OH METRO AREA","Auburn, NY Micro Area","Boston-Cambridge, MA-NH")
```

And I want it to look like

```
"Akron, OH", "Auburn, NY", "Boston-Cambridge, MA"
```

So just the City, State

Comment: What is the issue you are having?

Comment: Try `sub("(,\\s+[A-Z]+).*", "\\1", test)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option is `sub` from `base R` by matching one ore more space (`\\s+`) followed by  the `,` followed dby the upper case letters (`[A-Z]+`), capture as a group (`(...)`), in the `replacement`, specify the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
sub("(,\\s+[A-Z]+).*", "\\1", test)
#[1] "Akron, OH"            "Auburn, NY"           "Boston-Cambridge, MA"
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy option is a `stringr::str_extract`

```
test <- c("Akron, OH METRO AREA","Auburn, NY Micro Area","Boston-Cambridge, MA-NH")
stringr::str_extract(test, "[^,]+, .{0,2}")
# [1] "Akron, OH"            "Auburn, NY"           "Boston-Cambridge, MA"
```

We match anything that's not a comma, then a comma-space-then up to two more character.

Comment: Thanks! I always forget stringr cause I don't have much experience with regex. Makes sense!

Comment: Another one for you? If I have "Virginia Beach-Norfolk-Newport News, VA"
How can I make it into 3 rows
Virginia Beach, VA
Norfolk, VA
Newport News, VA

Comment: @user3304359 That's a different issue than what you've described here. Maybe open up a different question.